# Selecting data in html

Tags: html

am trying to select data and bring the info

like if i select john to bring john options

like to bring the selected user info only

i tried to use optgroup but not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <select name="category1" id="category1">
        <option value="">SELECT data</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="john">john data</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="fred">fred data</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="ken">ken data</OPTION>
    </select>
    
    <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
        <option value>SELECT info</option>
        <optgroup data-rel="john">
            <OPTION VALUE='age'>21</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='country'>usa</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='gender'>male</OPTION>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-rel="fred">
            <OPTION VALUE='age'>23</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='country'>uk</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='gender'>male</OPTION>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup data-rel="ken">
            <OPTION VALUE='age'>27</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='country'>canada</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE='gender'>male</OPTION>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean different data types in different option elemnts? Why not loading data into a div?

Comment: am using data-rel to define that when someone select john bring this optgroup options

Comment: Yes I realized that data of evey person is placed in an optgroup. But when you choose john you will see a select which contains 3 options (21,usa,male) So what? If you want to display or send data this structure is not usable. However if you need this structure for special purpose, you also need to say what script (Perhaps JavaScript) did you test so far and we check why it is not working? It is not possible to do that using pure HTML